# Multi-redirect for a simple form using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, redirect

Please can anyone help me on this form, I need to have this done pretty much right now for my client and I am lost!  Not the best at PHP. What needs to happen is whenever a user fills out the form it needs to redirect the URL based on the inputs added for the form. For example if they choose any of the drop-downs listed it will take them to that specific page.  I actually got all of that working through javascript as shown.  The next part where I need help is when they enter a correct zip code being that of San Diego, it will take them to the page that they chose in the drop-down.  If they don't input a correct zip code of San Diego, it will take them to a a different 'nation wide page'. Completely overriding the drop-down selections.  I really need help with this, can anyone please help me out?  Thanks for any input that can be added because I am super lost on what to do right now...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(nPage){

        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }
</script>

<?php
    $zip = $_GET['zip'];

    $sandiego =  array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173');

    if (in_array($zip, $sandiego)){
        header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
    } else {
            header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
    }

?>

<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'  id='gform_1'  action='front-page.php'>
<div class="serviceinput"
<label for="services">Services: </label>
<select id="selection" onchange="setAction(this.value)">

<option value=''>Select a Service</option>
<option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/'>Water Delivery</option>
<option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/'>Coffee Services</option>
<option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/'>Water Filtration</option>
</select>

</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="zipcode">
<label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
<input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" /></div>
<div class="frontradio"><input name="home" type="radio" id="homeradio" />
   <div class="homelabel"> <label for="homeradio">Home</label></div>
    <input name="home" type="radio" id="officeradio" />
    <label for="officeradio">Office</label></div>
<div class="homebutton">
<input type='submit' id="submithome" name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this functionality is what you need? You want to change the action of the form instead of handling the redirecting in one spot?

Let's start here:
Your form is using post, but you look for $_GET['zip']. You need to change that to listen for one or the other. Since this looks like a filtering form, I suggest using get:

```
<form method='get' id='gform_1' action='front-page.php'>
```

You don't need enctype there, and your method should be get. Now, your submission code should have isset around it:

```
if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
    $sandiego =  array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173');

    if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
        header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/"); // <- you sure about this?
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
    }
}
```

Your zip checker targets the same location for both. Perhaps you should utilize the select you made that currently has no name, so it won't populate in the get array:

```
    if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
        header("Location: ".urldecode($_GET['selection'])."?zip=".$_GET['zip']."&type=".$_GET['type']);
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
    }
    exit;
```

And make sure to give your selection input html a name:

```
<select name="selection">
```

You do not need that js unless you really feel like writing submission handling code in several different places or including it. PS - you don't want to do that. If you do, you're confused.

Your radio buttons need values and should probably have a less specific name:

```
<input name="type" type="radio" id="homeradio" value="home" />
<input name="type" type="radio" id="officeradio" value="office" />
```

You may want to update your question with the actual intention of this form. I would assume it is requesting service information. Like - you say you want water for home and it should take you to something like:

```
http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/?zip=xxxxx&type=home
```

This is pretty simple.

Your whole code would be something like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego =  array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173');

        if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
            header("Location: ".urldecode($_GET['selection'])."?zip=".$_GET['zip']."&type=".$_GET['type']);
        } else {
            header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
        }
        exit;
    }
?>
<form method='get' id='gform_1' action='front-page.php'>
  <div class="serviceinput">
    <label for="services">Services: </label>
    <select id="selection" name="selection">
      <option value=''>Select a Service</option>
      <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/'>Water Delivery</option>
      <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/'>Coffee Services</option>
      <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/'>Water Filtration</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="zipcode">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
    <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" />
  </div>
  <div class="frontradio">
    <input name="type" type="radio" id="homeradio" value="home" />
    <div class="homelabel"> <label for="homeradio">Home</label></div>
    <input name="type" type="radio" id="officeradio" value="office" />
    <label for="officeradio">Office</label>
  </div>
  <div class="homebutton">
    <input type='submit' id="submithome" name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
  </div>
</form>
```

A closing note, your code should verify there is a value selected for the service dropdown and just return errors instead of forcing the user around.

PS - your submission handling needs to be done BEFORE any html is sent to the browser. My example does not properly show a separation. It looks inline but that is not the intention. The form check code should happen as close to the top of the file as possible

**JAVASCRIPT EXAMPLE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sandiego = ['91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173'];
    var selection, zip, home;

    function sendForm(){
        zip = document.getElementById("selection").value;

        if(inArray(zip, sandiego))
        {
            selection = document.getElementById("selection").value;
            if(selection != "")
            {
                home = document.getElementById("home").value;
                var url = selection + '?zip=' + zip + '&home=' + home;
                window.location = url;
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            window.location = 'http://www.pureflo.com/';
        }
    }

    function inArray(needle, haystack) {
        var length = haystack.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, I had to move the parser to a new file called formhandler.php, now I am getting this as the url whenever I try to use the form in anyway at all:    http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/formhandler.php?selection=http%3A%2F%2F50.22.79.62%2F~pftech%2Fcoffee-delivery%2F&zip=92111&home=on&did_submit=Get+Started%21

Comment: http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/formhandler.php?selection=http%3A%2F%2F50.22.79.62%2F~pftech%2Fwater-delivery-service%2F&zip=92115&home=on&did_submit=Get+Started%21

Comment: I  updated a little. I forgot to urldecode $_GET['selection']. basically it does as expected. you go to formhandler.php?get-vars - that much is good. did you include the isset get zip code in formhandler.php?

Comment: forgot to urldecode $_GET['selection']... Not really sure what you mean here on this piece of code.  And yes I added everything you put the exact same way.  I think I am having trouble parse this form from formhandler.php because I am building this in Wordpress.  Where would I put the parser file at in Wordpress so it would work correctly.  Also not sure what you meant on your last message.  Let me know thanks for all of your amazing assistance today its been great!

Comment: Are you building this as a wordpress plugin? You really should be if you intend to integrate it into wordpress since it will help you avoid hacking core files to get this to work as you want. Here is a tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/ - but aside that, my answer was updated to show what I mean about urldecode. I put it in one of the header('location: xxx') lines. That will construct the url as it should be instead of having all the %20%3A jazz in there

Comment: Hey I am pretty confused about your last message again and the URL Decode, do I need to change any of the code above that you gave me or do I just leave it the same.  Also I am trying to just run this parser through 'formhandler.php', but I still get that long url that doesn't take me anywhere.  I am not sure how to build this handler into a plugin that will parse the front page form.  Can you give me a few tips on how I might be able to do that.  The tutorial you gave me is a huge tutorial on how to display items from a database, so I am not sure if that will help me.Please help anyway thanks

Comment: You could just do the whole thing in javascript since you're not actually posting anything. I updated my answer to include a crude example. Aside that, you don't need to follow the tutorials on wordpress, just get an idea of the architecture of a plugin. URL decode is a simple google search away from being totally understood AND where to use it exactly is in my example code. If any of this is confusing perhaps this should be outsourced

Answer (score 1):

check the method of your from :)
and after the `header()` use `exit` to prevent further execution of the php

```
<?php
    $zip = $_POST['zip']; //your form method is post

    $sandiego =  array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173');

    if (in_array($zip, $sandiego)){
        header("Location: ".$_POST['selection']);
        exit;
    } else {
            header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
            exit; 
   }

?>
```

Comment: I am gonna try this out right now thank you very much.  What do you mean by the method?  I just have the php within the same page, so I don't know if that can cause a problem or not? Should I put the parser within a different php file and use that file name as the method?

Comment: i mean when you have `<form method="post"` you have to use `$_POST` when you have `<form method="get"` you can use `$_GET` or you can use `$_REQUEST` that will work in both cases

Comment: Hey I just changed the form method to get and changed all cases of .$_POST to .$_GET.  After doing all of that I am getting this error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/pftech/public_html/wp-content/themes/pureflo/front-page.php on line 46     any idea where this error is coming from?

Comment: what is on line 46 you might mis an semicolon or bracket